# if statement or comparison C++

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++ but I'm facing comparing Problem

```
void print(int x, char const*b=""){
    std::cout << x;
    if(b == "a"){
    /*this code not execute I don't know why ?*/
      std::cout << "\n";
    }
}

/*calling my print function*/
print(2020, "a")
```

Comment: for string literals this applies: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004237/how-do-i-properly-compare-strings-in-c though using `std::string` is simpler

Comment: If you must use C-Strings (`char *`), then use the `str` family of functions, such as `strcmp`.

Answer (score 2):

Your check is validating the pointer's address
The empty string has an address in memory, so the check doesn't return true, thus the `if` true branch is not executed.

Is you are using C++ you might consider changing the argument to use type `std::string` and check using `std::string::empty`.

Comment: the above code also not working why ????

Comment: Because you are comparing pointers and not what they point to. if you are permitted remove the `char*` and use the proper `c++` string which is std::string. With a std::string the comparison would work just by changing `void print(int x, char const*b=""){` to `void print(int x, std::string b){` and adding `#include <string>`